# Setup options for an HP Storageworks D2600 Array

Tags: raid, storage, vmware-esxi

I have a shiny, new D2600 storage array with 6 x 2TB disks fitted, together with the licence pack that allows me to configure this all as a RAID 6 array. A few questions for you:

1) The array has two SAS controllers - can these be connected to two separate servers for fault tolerance and dual-access? One server has a P411 array controller and I have a P600 I could fit into a second.

2) As far as I can see, the BIOS-based config utility in the P411 controller will only let me create a single, RAID 6 LUN. Is it possible to setup a RAID 6 array and then divide the available storage into multiple LUNs? Specifically, this is so I can create several 2TB datastores for VMware ESXi.

If this is not possible, what options are worth considering to make all this storage available for ESXi - for example I have read elsewhere about using a separate server (in a VM?) to make the array available via iSCSi or NFS.

3) If I setup the Array on the P411 controller and then connect it later to the P600, will the P600 see it properly and allow correct access? I am thinking of the option to have the P600 card in a 'standby server' that can run the array if the main server croaks.

Any pointers or guidance appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Might want to consider doing detailed planning before purchasing gear next time. Just a thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) The D2600 isn't supported by the P600, although you could, if you really wanted to you could cable two servers to the disk enclosure, though that isn't what this box was designed for I'm almost certain it wouldn't be supported in this configuration - I'm also pretty sure you could easily corrupt your data almost immediately this way too.

2) Yes, the P411 can create a single array of all your disks and then create multiple 2TB logical disks for ESXi. You don't mention what tools you're trying to do this with but I would suggest using the ACU tool on the SmartStart CD if you can, it's a GUI and very easy for beginners to deal with compared to ORCA or CPQONLIN.

3) The D2600 isn't supported by the P600, though the array will happily move between other P411, P212 and P812 controller with ease.

Comment: Thanks @Chopper3. Is there any way to get the P411 passed through to a Windows Server 2003 VM running on the ESXi server to configure the array - not having much luck with this part - or is it easier to do this on a standalone machine?

Comment: Erm...well perhaps but it would be complex and shakey, just download the smartstart CD for your server from hp.com, burn to CD, boot, run ACU - job done.